# Which exceptions can be thrown by XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using .NET XmlSerializer, XmlSchema and XmlReader to deserialize an XML document. Which exceptions may be thrown during validation and deserialization, since there are so many classes involved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN knows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdxxw552.aspx).  Just go look at every method that you're using.